# nuxt:imports-transform - can't read properties of undefined

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nuxt3

Recently upgraded to nuxt v.3.8.0.

Running  `npm run dev´ gives this error:

```
 ERROR  Internal server error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'includes')
  Plugin: nuxt:imports-transform
  File: /Users/tor/projects/nuxtapp/mixins/module-pinia.js
      at file:///Users/tor/projects/nuxtapp/node_modules/unimport/dist/shared/unimport.0a3f1751.mjs:952:62
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at Object.injectImportsWithContext [as injectImports] (file:///Users/tor/projects/nuxtapp/node_modules/unimport/dist/shared/unimport.0a3f1751.mjs:949:22)
      at async TransformContext.transform (file:///Users/tor/projects/nuxtapp/node_modules/nuxt/dist/index.mjs:2014:21)
      at async file:///Users/tor/projects/nuxtapp/node_modules/vite-plugin-inspect/dist/index.mjs:922:19
      at async Object.transform (file:///Users/tor/projects/nuxtapp/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:44352:30)
      at async loadAndTransform (file:///Users/tor/projects/nuxtapp/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:55026:29)
      at async viteTransformMiddleware (file:///Users/tor/projects/nuxtapp/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-bb8a8339.js:64430:32)
```

If I downgrade to nuxt 3.7.0 it's working.

Not sure if this is a nuxt issue or not. I haven't been able to recreate the problem.
If I start a new project using nuxt 3.8.0 it works as normal.
But in this one I get the error.

Tried removing package-lock.json, delete node_modules with `npm cache clear --force` and `npm install`.
Still same error.

REPRODUCTION:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-g9ceqa?file=app.vue,stores%2Findex.js,mixins%2FmyMixin.ts